# How to Secure Webhook using basic authentication - Bitbucket webhook

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-webhook

My endpoint uses basic authentication (a username and password), I want to use this method to secure my webhook. When the webhook data is sent, the authorisation header will be included  in the HTTP request.

I don't see any option to send basic auth token to webhook. I can only see `Secret` field while creating the webhook.

how to incorporate Basic Authentication for bitbucket webhook?